Solution to Stochastic Differential Equation Including Heaviside Step Function
There has been several entries on solving deterministic differential equations that include indicator functions. Stochastic differential equations may introduce new difficulties. Namely, does the usual technique used in the deterministic situation, of dividing the domain into intervals, still apply?
Take the following SDE:
$$dX_t=(\mu dt+\sigma dW_t)\theta(X_t)$$
Here, $\theta$
is the unit step function whose jump is located at the origin, $W_t$
the Weiner process, and $\mu$
and $\sigma$
Real-valued constants.
Can a general (closed form) solution be produced?

is $\theta [0,1]$ valued? looks like a first passage problem

Yes, $\theta$ is the unit step so is an element of $[0,1]$ - thanks for inviting the clarification

OK, so when $X$ hits 0 it is stuck, correct? This is diffusion with sticking boundary condtions, and can probably be treated with the method of images.

Indeed, it is an absorbing boundary. I'd be happy to hear more about using the method of images here

nice review: https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.17656
